# How can I install an app directly on my SD card?

Tags: motorola-moto-g

I would like to install a 4.0Go app but my internal memory only has less than 1.0Go free. However, my SD card has 32.0Go free space. How do i install the app? I have a Motorola 2G

Comment: You can try using adb install -s your.apk

Comment: @user3344236 I doubt that would work, as `adb install` in the first step needs to copy the `.apk` to the device – where it usually is (temporarily) placed in internal storage. Whether there's a possibility at all also depends on how much of the app in question can be moved to SD card (remember that with App2SD, parts of the app always remain in internal storage). If that fits, there's a small chance to `adb push your.apk /sdcard/your.apk && adb shell "pm install /sdcard/your.apk"` – though I'm not entirely sure if that wouldn't trigger the same issue.

Comment: http://www.makeuseof.com/answers/how-can-i-directly-install-apps-to-my-phones-sd-card-from-the-google-play-store/   and http://www.fixedbyvonnie.com/2014/06/install-android-apps-sd-card-default/

Answer (score 0):

This is only allowable with certain apps, on a per app basis. if the app doesn't allow it, you can't move it to run/work on an external SD card.